# passing the return of a function into another function in python

Tags: python, pygame

I am absolutely overlooking something basic here... I'm trying to pass the return of a function (a list of lists) into another function as an argument. When i compile i get the error that the gameGridWords variable is not defined.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

This is the function that returns gameGridWords:

```
# Populates the tile grid with random word pairs
###########################################################################    
def gridWords():    
    # Picks 18 random words from text file to a list, doubles list and shuffles it, returns a list with 18 pairs of words
    words = [line.strip() for line in open("words.txt", 'r')]      
    randomWords=[]             
    for i in range(0, 18):
        element=random.randint(0, len(words)-1)
        randomWords.append(words[element])    
    randomWords.extend(randomWords)
    randomWordPairs=randomWords
    random.shuffle(randomWordPairs)

    # Populates the game grid with word pairs
    gameGridWords=[]
    for row in range(6):
        columnls=[]
        for column in range(6):
            columnls.append(randomWordPairs[0])
            del randomWordPairs[0] 
        gameGridWords.append(columnls)
    #print (gameGridWords)
    return gameGridWords
```

This is the function that generates the error:

```
# Draws the game grid and fills it with 18 pairs of random words
###########################################################################  
def drawGrid(gameGridWords, revealed=True):

    # Background color
    gameDisplay.fill(BLACK) 
    # Draws the grid with gray tiles and populates it with random word pairs
    for row in range(6):
            for column in range(6):
                if not revealed:
                    color = GRAY
                    pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay,color,[(MARGIN + WIDTH) * column + MARGIN,(MARGIN + HEIGHT) * row + MARGIN,WIDTH,HEIGHT])

                else:
                    word_display(gameGridWords[row][column], BLACK, row, column)
    """
    # Fills tiles with blue 
    for row in range(6):
        for column in range(6):
            if grid[row][column] == 1:
                color = BLUE
                pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay,color,[(MARGIN + WIDTH) * column + MARGIN,(MARGIN + HEIGHT) * row + MARGIN,WIDTH,HEIGHT])

    """

    timer()      
    tryCounter()
    #pygame.display.update()
```

I call gridWords() inside my gameLoop() function outside my actual while loop.

I call drawGrid() in my gameLoop() inside the while loop with : drawGrid(gameGridWords, True) The error i get is as follows:

Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\Users\Mileta Nikoletic\OneDrive\Eclipse workspace\Python\P-UPPGIFT DD1316\Memory\test6.py", line 440, in gameIntro()

File "C:\Users\Mileta Nikoletic\OneDrive\Eclipse workspace\Python\P-UPPGIFT DD1316\Memory\test6.py", line 192, in gameIntro button("Play (space bar)", 150,400,250,50, GRAY, BLUE, action="play")

File "C:\Users\Mileta Nikoletic\OneDrive\Eclipse workspace\Python\P-UPPGIFT DD1316\Memory\test6.py", line 154, in button gameLoop()

File "C:\Users\Mileta Nikoletic\OneDrive\Eclipse workspace\Python\P-UPPGIFT DD1316\Memory\test6.py", line 423, in gameLoop

drawGrid(gameGridWords, True)
NameError: name 'gameGridWords' is not defined

If i passed gameGridWords into drawGrid, than i assume that gameGridWords would be defined?

Thanks for your patience!

Comment: Can you include the error in your post?

Comment: What about the call to `gridWords()` that populates `gameGridWords` ?

Comment: `drawGrid(gridWords())` ?

Comment: I can see the function definitions but I can't see how they are called in Milnik's code. We'd need that plus the full error.

Comment: Do you have a statement like `gameGridWords = gridWords()` - if not how are you assigning `gameGridWords` ? That seems to be the key to the problem. If you're just calling `gridWords()` that only creates a local variable `gameGridWords` which disappears when you return from the function.

Comment: Can we see the code between your call to `gridWords()` and were you call `drawGrid(gameGridWords, revealed=True)`? There's no error in the code you've provided so we must have that code to find an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have to assign data returned by first function to variable ie.

```
result = gridWords()
```

and later use this data with second function.

```
drawGrid(result)
```

(btw. name `result` doesn't matter, you can use different name)

if second function isn't in the same function but in subfunction then you have to send `result` to this subfunction and this subfunction has to send it to your function

```
result = gridWords()
subfunction(result)

def subfunction(data):
    drawGrid(data)
```